# Link error cannot open input file opencv_world440.lib when trying to install extra modules + CUDA

Tags: opencv

I am following [this tutorial](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/accelerate-opencv-4-2-0-build-with-cuda-and-python-bindings/) to install OpenCV with extra modules and CUDA.

I got to the step where I see the OpenCV.sln solution file in `PATH_TO_OPENCV_SOURCE/build` directory, where I have `PATH_TO_OPENCV_SOURCE` as `C:/Users/me/Downloads/opencv-master`

I then opened that in Visual Studio 2017, right clicked on Install and clicked on Build. I now see a bunch of `error cannot open input file ..\..\lib\Release\opencv_world440.lib` errors.

I noticed that in `C:/Users/me/Downloads/opencv-master/build/lib/Release` that I see `opencv_ts440.lib` but not `opencv_world440.lib`

in VS, when I go to Configuration Properties, I don't see `C/C++` or `additional include directories` anywhere

can anyone help with this?

Comment: For this kind of problems, it can be helpful to add cuda version, OS info, GPU info, opencv version etc.

Comment: I'm using CUDA 10.2 in Windows 7. I'm using OpenCV 4.3.0, and the latest version of the extra modules obtained from the Github